# Flickering the tab content using angular material tabs

Tags: angular-material

I have a dynamic tab content and moving from from tab to another, the tab content got flickering.

```
<md-tabs md-dynamic-height class="md-primary">
        <md-tab data-ui-sref="common.usermanagement.userclassmaintenance" md-active="$state.includes('common.usermanagement.userclassmaintenance')">
            <md-tab-label>
                User-class Maintenance
            </md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-body> 
                <md-content ng-cloak flex layout="column" class="md-padding">                       
                    <div data-ui-view="userclassmaintenance"></div>                        
                </md-content>                           
            </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>    

        <md-tab data-ui-sref="common.usermanagement.usermaintenance" md-active="$state.includes('common.usermanagement.usermaintenance')">
            <md-tab-label>
                User Maintenance
            </md-tab-label>
            <md-tab-body>               
                <md-content ng-cloak flex layout="column" class="md-padding">                       
                    <div data-ui-view="usermaintenance"></div>               
                </md-content>                           
            </md-tab-body>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
```

And i also included the following portion of CSS which i have got it from  some another article. But not working for me.

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Seems okay - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/xOyPPz

Comment: @camden_kid, i have a form with many fields and that is causing flickering

Comment: did not get any flickering if the data is in same page, but i am getting problem with separated content with data-ui-sref

Comment: Could you add the form markup to your question?

Comment: Same issues I am facing..any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar situation with `mat-tab`.
I was using the following code:

```
<mat-tab-group dynamicHeight="true">
    <mat-tab label="Pivot View">
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <app-missing-data-pivot [requestBody]="dataSource"></app-missing-data-pivot>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The `dynamicHeight="true"` was causing my elements inside the tab to flicker. I removed that, and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure flickering is not caused by spinner & overlay that is showed for just a few miliseconds!